# Can I use Time Capsule to run programs and processes in the background?

Tags: terminal, time-capsule, macos

I want to install homebridge onto my Time Capsule, but I was wondering if that is possible. Can I install things and run them on Time Capsule via a Terminal window on my Mac? It would be super helpful to have homebridge running on my Time Capsule instead of my Mac because sometimes I shut my Mac down and I would like to have homebridge running on a device that is always on.

Answer (score 1):

You can't run any of your own processes on the Time Capsule itself. The closest you can get is to put the files on the Time Capsule, then run the application from a Mac over the network. The Time Capsule doesn't act as a standalone computer.

Comment: Ok, can it run like a background process or anything like that?

Comment: @Harish No, I've edited my answer to clarify I meant all processes in my answer.

Comment: Ahh, gotcha! Thanks :).. I might look at getting raspberry pi to run homebridge.